# error "Invalid input: alias_email" when using service.users.aliases.insert in javascript

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm getting an error "Invalid input: alias_email" when using service.users.aliases.insert in javascript.  Here is my code:

```
  const service = google.admin('directory_v1');
  service.users.aliases.insert({
    auth: auth,
    userKey: "<valid e-mail address>",
    body: {
        alias: "<valid alias in e-mail format>"
    }
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      console.dir(err);
      return;
    }
```

The error message (code 400) is:

```
domain:"global"
message:"Invalid Input: alias_email"
reason:"invalid"
```

I've tried to use exactly the same  and  in the online api tester (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/aliases/insert), where it functions correctly.

I've also tried to delete an existing alias, which functions correctly:

```
service.users.aliases.delete({
        auth: auth,
        userKey: "<valid e-mail address>",
        alias: "<valid alias in e-mail format>"
      }, function(err, response) {
```

What is wrong with the insert call?
I've been searching for quite some time now.  Any help very much appreciated.  Thx!